# How do I allow a device to only connect to certain wifi networks?

Tags: wifi, sysadmin

I have been assigned to a task that a laptop should be connected to particular wifi Network, i.e Laptop should not connect with any other wifi network other than office wifi. is that possible??? any help could be appreciated...

Comment: What OS? Windows or Linux? AD joined or not? Does the user have admin rights?

Comment: In windows, joined AD, for admin user and standard user both..

Answer (score 0):

https://www.maketecheasier.com/block-wifi-network-windows10/

```
netsh wlan delete filter permission=allow ssid="WiFi Network Name" networktype=infrastructure

netsh wlan delete filter permission=denyall networktype=infrastructure
```